# how to notify when stock levels have reached below a certain level c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm stuck with a part of a project. 
I have a database set up in SQL server with a table called stockTable which keep account of the four different types of materials needed.

I am using c# and ASP.net and doing this is Visual studio 2013.

I ultimately want to be able to be notified when these stock levels have reached below a certain level (EG: 200) and then email the manager to order some more materials.

I have the materials within a table and they are out putted by using a placeholder.

I am unsure in how to check the values in this placeholder and compare it to a standard level (EG:200).

This is how the table is created and shown on the webform.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ToString();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from [StockTable]";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        table.Append("<table border='1'>");
        table.Append("<tr><th>ID</th><th>Amount Of Stickers</th><th>Amount of Small Jars</th><th>Amount of Large Jars</th><th> Amount of Lids</th>");
        table.Append("</tr>");

        if (rd.HasRows)
        {
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                table.Append("<tr>");
                table.Append("<td>" + rd[0] + "</td>");
                table.Append("<td>" + rd[1] + "</td>");
                table.Append("<td>" + rd[2] + "</td>");
                table.Append("<td>" + rd[3] + "</td>");
                table.Append("<td>" + rd[4] + "</td>");
                table.Append("</tr>");
            }
        }
        table.Append("</table");
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = table.ToString() });
        rd.Close();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this, was thinking an if statement comparing the values but i am unsure of how to go about this.

if a anyone has suggestions or snippets of code, it would be greatly appreciated, or easier ways in order to email the manager when stock levels are low.

Comment: you are correct, just an if statement to check for a certain amount (maybe defined in a config or other database table) after you have read the values from the database

Comment: Your code is unclear. Do you have a _stockTable_ with many rows with different ID of the same 4 items? Or do you have 4 records with the total of the 4 items?

Comment: @DZDomi how would i construct this if statement comparing one value from the database to a minimum level? thank you for your help.

Comment: @Steve I have one row with all the same Id (7) and four different values within this row. (EG: ID, AmountOfStickers, AmountOfSmallJars, AmountOfLargeJars, AmountOfLids). thank you for your help!

Comment: It would really help if you showed us the schema of StockTable. What do you want to know “reached below a certain level”? Any column of any row? The sum of columns of any row? The sum of rows of any column? All rows of all columns?

Comment: Unfortunately too broad. **Ideally** you would do inventory mgmt outside of the web application (e.g. scheduled task). _IF_ you're going to do this on the web application, then you _ideally_ should do this _after_ an order is submitted, given that's the time something is actually taken out of inventory. Otherwise, your managers will scream at you for all the spam notifications just because someone is browsing your site (not purchasing nor touching inventory at all). Hth

Comment: @DourHighArch I have a table in my database called stockTable which has only one row with the following in the row: ID, AmountOfStickers, AmountOfSmallJars, AmountOfLargeJars, AmountOfLids. I am currently able to add stock to these materials to increase, edit or update them, but i also want to add a function that a messagebox or some notification type will be displayed if  one of these materials goes beyond a certain level (eg:200)

Comment: @EdSF this is not for customer to order etc, this is for the business itself, therefore nobody will be browsing the website, but only the manager itself as it is a system for admin.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48141907/edit) your question to include the code like `CREATE TABLE stockTable (ID INT IDENTITY, ...`. Do not try to describe code in prose in comments.